# how does incorrect Docker postGIS command RUN succesfully?

Tags: docker

I was just having a look at this postgreSQL image [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/), the image is postGIS enabled. See the dockerfile that builds the image , it looks as follows:

```
FROM postgres:9.4
MAINTAINER Mike Dillon <mike@appropriate.io> 
ENV POSTGIS_MAJOR 2.1 
ENV POSTGIS_VERSION 2.1.7+dfsg-3~94.git954a8d0.pgdg80+1 
RUN apt-get update \ && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \ postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-postgis-$POSTGIS_MAJOR=$POSTGIS_VERSION \ postgis=$POSTGIS_VERSION \ && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
RUN mkdir -p /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d COPY ./initdb-postgis.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgis.sh
```

Notice the environment variable for postGIS:

```
ENV POSTGIS_VERSION 2.1.7+dfsg-3~94.git954a8d0.pgdg80+1
```

Also have a look at the RUN command, like follows:

```
RUN apt-get update \ && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \ postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-postgis-$POSTGIS_MAJOR=$POSTGIS_VERSION \ postgis=$POSTGIS_VERSION \ && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

So basically the postGIS image is being constructed using the below command:

```
postgis=$POSTGIS_VERSION
```

Now, if you go to docker hub and type in the search bar "postgis" , you will get no official repository.

Secondly, from the command line if i execute the following command:

```
sudo docker pull postgis
```

I get a message that a repository does not exists.

if the repository does not exists, how does the postgreSQl(which is postGIS enabled) image successfully build ?? I.E. how is the below script correct ?

```
FROM postgres:9.4
MAINTAINER Mike Dillon <mike@appropriate.io> 
ENV POSTGIS_MAJOR 2.1 
ENV POSTGIS_VERSION 2.1.7+dfsg-3~94.git954a8d0.pgdg80+1 
RUN apt-get update \ && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \ postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-postgis-$POSTGIS_MAJOR=$POSTGIS_VERSION \ postgis=$POSTGIS_VERSION \ && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
RUN mkdir -p /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d COPY ./initdb-postgis.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgis.sh
```

Thank you.

Comment: re: docker pull - unless you've built your own image and called it postgis, you'd need to give the fully qualified name (it's not a library image) i.e. `docker pull mdillon/postgis`

Comment: @booyaa , thats exactly what i said in my question !!!!!! , i am asking how does the script work ?? I.E. how does the `mdillon/postgis` docker file run ? when actually there is no `postgis` image

Comment: You seem to be confusing debian packages with docker hub images...

Comment: @AdrianMouat , thanks for pointing that out , give me an example !

Comment: Packages installed with `apt-get` have nothing to do with images pulled via `docker pull`.  The `apt-get update` command is installing *packages* inside your container.

Comment: @larsks , thanks you , !